# Is it possible to use docker remote API in the same fashion as regular API?

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I want to copy local script files to a remote host and run one of them. On a local host I would use these commands:

```
docker run -d python tail -f /dev/null
docker cp ./ <id>:/usr/local/bin/
docker exec <id> python /usr/local/bin/script.py
```

I'd like to add an additional command specifying IP and port of a remote machine

The official site [suggests](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) to use curl. There is a [list](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/remote_api_client_libraries/) of docker clients, but all of them are supposed to be used programmatically.

I'd prefer to run those commands from console or, to put them into a `.bat` file. Why is there an additional level of complexity introduced by curl/ setting a project in some language to run three commands? Does docker-toolbox allow to execute commands on a remote host?

Answer (score 1):

The `docker` command line can work against remote Docker Engines in the same way as the local engine - it uses environment variables to specify the details of the API it should connect to.

`docker-machine` wraps this up neatly with the [env](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/) command, but you can do it with the regular `docker` CLI by setting these variables:

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/nathanleclaire/.docker/machines/.client
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

Using your own remote host address and certs.

By default the Docker Engine API isn't exposed to remote clients, so you'll need to configure it - [Using TLS with the Docker Engine](https://integratedcode.us/2015/07/29/using-tls-with-the-docker-engine/) shows you how.

Comment: I set up it on the server without encryption

`DOCKER_OPTS='-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock'` 

http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2014/07/quick-tip-how-to-enable-docker-remote-api.html

In windows, I ceated an environment variable `DOCKER_HOST`, set it to `tcp://my.ip.address:port` and restarted the toolbox. On start it prints "docker is configured to use the default machine with ip 192.168.99.100". The commands are executed on a local instance.

Comment: The toolbox terminal runs in its own user session, so you either need to set a system variable, or set the environment variable inside the toolbox terminal.